# Show form validation errors on the same page at the right side of the input box

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and working on a project.

I want to validate a login and register page using PHP.

I want to validate the form in the same field and display the error on right side of the input box.

I tried many times but I am not successful. I can do it with JavaScript/jQuery, but I am unable to do it with PHP.

My form contains:

```
email : inputbox - error div
password : input box -error div
submit button
```

Can you explain how to do this with PHP?

Comment: What is the specific issue you are having? In it's current form it is very hard to tell what you are looking for. The entire text without any capitalization also doesn't really help.

Comment: ok. petra, i just want to validate the form on same page with display inline errors...

Answer (score 1):

You can let the form post to itself and verify the post data on submit. Something like:

```
<?php

$errors = array();

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // do some validation and fill $errors variable when something is wrong

    // if everything is fine e.g. redirect user
    header('Location: http://example.com/success');
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email">
  <?php if ($errors['email']) { echo '<div class="error">' . $errors['email'] . '</div>'; } ?>
  <input type="password" name="password">
  <?php if ($errors['password']) { echo '<div class="error">' . $errors['password'] . '</div>'; } ?>
  <input type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: where i have to take the form data inside the condition of outside the condition, means $email=$_POST['email'] or so on...

Comment: I would initialize the variables outside the condition and fill them inside.

Comment: i am still unable to solve this. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can'tdo it with php... php is ran at the server, the only possible way to do it with php is also using jquery or js (and ajax)...

Comment: if javascript is disable in anyone system is it works??

Comment: no, but you can tell them to activate it using <noscript>. Whatever is inside that tag, it will only be displayed to those who haven't disabled js. Write something like <noscript>Please, enable javascript in order to see this site properly</noscript>