# How do I make my PHP form errors show on the same page?

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a simple contact form with some PHP validation attached to it. However, when a field if left blank and the form is thrown one of these errors, it redirects to a blank page and just echos out the error on a blank screen. How would I go about keeping these errors on the same page? The errors don't have to validate instantly, just when someone clicks send. Optimally it would just direct to the contact form page and have an added string of text about the form that tells the user that there was an error.

PHP

```
<?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
$subject = trim($_POST["subject"]);
$message = trim($_POST["message"]);
if ($name == "") {
    // header("Location: contact.php");
    echo "You must speciy a value for name.";
    exit;
}
if ($email == "") {
    // header("Location: contact.php");
    echo "You must speciy a value for email.";
    exit;
}
if ($subject == "") {
    // header("Location: contact.php");
    echo "You must speciy a value for subject.";
    exit;
}
if ($message == "") {
    // header("Location: contact.php");
    echo "You must speciy a value for message.";
    exit;
}
foreach( $_POST as $value ) {
    if( stripos($value,'Content-Type:') !== FALSE ){
        echo "There was a problem with the information you entered.";
        exit;
    }
}
if ($_POST["address"] != "") {
    echo "Your submission has an error.";
    exit;
}

require_once("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer();

if (!$mail-> ValidateAddress($email)){
  echo "You must specify a valid email address";
  exit;
}

$email_body = "";
$email_body = $email_body . "Name: " . $name . "<br>";
$email_body = $email_body . "Email: " . $email . "<br>";
$email_body = $email_body . "Subject: " . $subject . "<br>";
$email_body = $email_body . "Message: " . $message . "<br>";

$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress('email@gmail.com', 'Staff');
$mail->Subject = "Contact Form | " . $name;
$mail->msgHTML($email_body);

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "There was a problem sending the email: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
}
header("Location: contact.php?status=thanks");
exit;
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<div id="contact-form">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <form class="form" method="post">
                            <p class="name">
                            <div id="label"><label for="name">Name</label></div>
                            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="John Doe" />
            </p>

            <p class="email">
            <div id="label"><label for="email">Email</label></div>
                        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="mail@example.com" />
            </p>

            <p class="subject">
                    <div id="label"><label for="subjext">Subject</label></div>
            <select name="subject" id="subject">
            <option></option>
            <option>Request for Consultation</option>
            <option>Ordering a Service</option>
            <option>Just to Say Hello</option>
            <option>Other</option>
            </select>
            </p>

            <p class="message">
            <div id="label"><label for="message">Message</label></div>
                            <textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Write something to us" /></textarea>
            </p>

                            <div id="label" class="address" style="display:none !important"><label for="address">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="address" id="address" placeholder="123 Elm Street" />
                <p>If you're a human, please leave this field blank.</p>
                </div>

            <p class="submit">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn-blue btn-submit"/>
            </p>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are looking for **ajax**. However this question right now is not very well suited for SO, try to show some research, not just throwing your problem at us

Comment: You can do it through javascript either.

Comment: See [Show form validation errors on the same page at the right side of the input box](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11923376) on mixing HTML and PHP to output messages in place. Some form management and validation class would make it less tedious, as might the AJAX approach or HTML5 client side validation rules.

Comment: Have done research on it. Tried jquery but couldn't seem to get that to fix the problem and that is the recommendation on 90% of answers. ajax is a new solution to me. I know how to use google, just not jquery very well.

Answer (score 0):

Two basic options...

(1) Include the error message as part of the URL.

```
header("Location: contact.php?error=" . urlencode("You must specify a value for name."));
```

You can then, in `contact.php` add a `echo $_GET["error"];` in the appropriate place.

Biggest downside here is potential for abuse. A message included in the URL can be changed by the user, or anyone to display anything. Someone malicious might change the message to confuse or abuse a user.

(2) Use sessions to store the error message.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["error"] = "You must specific a value for name.";
```

And then on `contact.php`, at the top add a `session_start();` and somewhere in the page add...

```
if ($_SESSION["error"] != "") {
  echo $_SESSION["error"];
  $_SESSION["error"] = "";
}
```

There are more ways, but this should get you started.

Comment: Thanks Andy. For sure going to take a look at sessions as well as an ajax solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do this with PHP if you do not have a great knowledge of Javascript or AJAX.  You have 2 options: one of them is overcomplicated, but I will give you both anyway.

**Option #1:**

Send the form to the same page.

Change the action of the form to send it to whatever page the form itself is on.  Then, when you want to do the error messages, instead of doing

```
echo "insert error message here";
```

for the first error msg, in your case if they left name empty, you want to do

```
$errormsg = "insert error message here";
```

for every other validation, you want to do

```
$errormsg .= "insert error message here";
```

then, just echo out the

```
$errormsg
```

if it is not null.

**Option #2**

This option is very overdone.  It has the same concept as above, but it adds support for if you want to have the form on the other page.

Make sure you have

```
session_start();
```

on the top of both the form page and the form validation php page.

now, for the first errormsg that occurs:

```
$_SESSION['errormsg'] = "insert error message here";
```

For every other error msg after that, you can do

```
$_SESSION['errormsg'] .= "insert error message here";
```

as we did before.